# MATLAB : Does the qr algorithm and the DGEMM used in MATLAB take into account if the input matrix is tridigonal and optimize accordingly?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's say we want to solve for the eigen-values of a symmetric matrix of size $n$ x $n$.

In the Phase 1 of the computation, the matrix is reduced to a tridigonal form using Householder/Arnoldi's reduction.The theory says that this is $O(n^3)$.

In the Phase 2 of the computation, this tridigonal form is transformed to a diagonal form by using the **Normalized Simultaneous Iteration (NSI)**. The two main steps in this iteraion are matrix multiplication of tridigonal matrices and the **qr** factorization of a tridigonal matrix. Each of these (if implemented specially for tridigonal systems) will be $O(n)$. Since these are to be repeated $n$ times, the total would be $O(n^2)$.

I want to see experimentally that the phase 1 actually reduces the time for computation. The easist way to do this is in **MATLAB** which uses the **DGEMM** routine for matrix multiplication and Householder reflector for **qr** factorization.

My question is : Does the **qr** algorithm and the **DGEMM** used in **MATLAB** take into account if the input matrix is tridigonal and optimize accordingly ? The documentation says that it differentiates between sparse and dense matrices.

If I have to write a code separately for matrix multiplication of tridigonal systems and a **qr** using householder reflector, will it be better than the ones provided in **MATLAB** ?

Is there a way to do this using something other than MATLAB , like a C or C++ library ?

Comment: Are you looking for routines that can efficiently compute eigenvalues of tridiagonal symmetric matrices? If so, have a look at `dsteqr` or `dsterf` (both are LAPACK routines). Both have an asymptotic ${\cal O}(n^2)$ cost. More information [here](http://www.nag.com/numeric/fl/nagdoc_fl22/xhtml/F08/f08jef.xml).

Comment: Also, MATLAB has the built-in `isbanded` function that can detect the bandwidth of a given (sparse) matrix. It's not inconceivable to assume that they test for tridiagonal matrices somewhere in their `qr` implementation...

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking Matlab's `eig`, `qr` and `*`? Are they $O(n^3)$ or $O(n^2)$, with a tridiagonal matrix as input? It shouldn't take long to code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a short Matlab benchmark. I've used a sparse tridiagonal matrix.

```
function benchmark_qr

maxit = 25;
time = zeros(maxit,2);

for iter = 1:maxit

    mdim = 500 * iter;

    A = gallery('tridiag',mdim,-2,3,-2);

    t_start_qr = tic;
    qr(A);
    t_elapsed_qr = toc(t_start_qr);

    t_start_eig = tic;
    eig(A);
    t_elapsed_eig = toc(t_start_eig);

    time(iter,1) = mdim;
    time(iter,2) = t_elapsed_qr;
    time(iter,3) = t_elapsed_eig;

end

figure
loglog(time(:,1),time(:,2),'rs--')
hold on
loglog(time(:,1),time(:,3),'kd--')
loglog(time(:,1),(time(:,1)/100).^2,'--')
loglog(time(:,1),(time(:,1)/100).^3,'-.')
legend('qr','eig','N^2','N^3','Location','northwest');

end
```

The results suggest that both `eig` and `qr` are ${\cal O}(n^2)$ for sufficiently large $n$:

[image]

Comment: Why the `loglog`? The flop count is $f = {\cal O}(n^2)$, that is $f \le C n^2$ for sufficiently large $n$ (with $C$ a constant independent of $n$). Taking logarithms, we get $\log f \sim 2 \log n + \log C$ - a linear relationship with slope $2$ - something much easier to visualize and understand than the original (quadratic) equation.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. Now I'm trying the same thing for general matrices. I want to know if it is $O(n^3)$ or $O(n^2)$.

Comment: `qr` is ${\cal O}(n^3)$ for general matrices. Define $A$ as `A = rand(n)` in my example to convince yourself that is the case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you said it looks like qr and even matrix multiplication is $O(n^3)$ for eneral matrices in MATLAB.

Comment: @SrinivasK That should not be a surprise.